# Tracnsact SQL Fetch Performance

Tags: t-sql, fetch

Hi i want to make a stored procedure that will join 2 table and will check some values to update.
We will use FETCH to make a update process for each record.

But we are considering performance. Is this a bad idea to use FETCH?

Example:

Table1
BookID
BookName

Table2
RatingID
BookName
BookID

We will join this two tables like this.

```
SELECT * FROM Table2
LEFT JOIN Table1 ON Table2.BookName = Table1.BookName 
WHERE Table2.BookID = 0
```

For each record which this query pulls, we will make an UPDATE to set Table1's bookID to Table2's BookID column.

Comment: FETCH as in via a CURSOR? if so then yes that's not usually an efficient way of doing things, you will need to provide more details.

Comment: @Alex Yes FETCH as in via a cursor. Also i updated my question.

Comment: You say "we will make an UPDATE to set Table1's bookID to Table2's BookID column." Are you sure your `WHERE` condition is the right way round then and you shouldn't be checking `WHERE Table1.BookID = 0`? Also no point in using an `OUTER` join here I would have thought as you are only interested in rows that match in both tables?

Comment: Yes we will make update for only which rows that match in both tables, and we are not gonna check `WHERE Table1.BookID = 0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

You should nearly always strive to avoid cursors in SQL Server and use set based alternatives instead.

The `UPDATE` statement does support `JOIN`s to other tables.

Comment: Updates to large tables can sometimes cause table locks which will impact users. To get around this you can use a cursor to process the query in smaller batches.

Comment: @McMinton - It would be better to use a CTE that contains `TOP (@batchsize)` then update the CTE IMO.

Answer (score 2):

(As usual) What Martin said.

Also, based on your description, the update would look something like this (for SQL Server):

```
UPDATE Table1
 set BookID = t2.BookID
 from Table1 t1
  inner join Table2 t2
   on t2.BookName = t1.BookName
 where T2.BookID = 0
```

- Inner joins, becasue of the where clause; with `Table2.BookID = 0`, Table2 rows not matched by the join but included anyway by the *outer* join will be discarded, as their BookID will always be NULL
- Similarly setting Table1's BookId to Table2's BookId will always set it to 0, because the where clause says "where Table2.BookId = 0". You might want to rethink this...?

Comment: No. We will set Table1's BookID to Table2's BookID column so its not gonna be 0 always. But now i prefer update command without using CURSOR thanks.